# Poise cookbook failing with compilation error

Tags: macos, chef-infra, cookbook

**I am getting compile error on poise cookbook . i started to get this error starting yesterday. was there any change done recently ? or do we have fix for this ??**

> ## =============================================================================== Recipe Compile Error in
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/libraries/default.rb
>
> ArgumentError
> ------------- wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
>
> Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
> ----------------------------------------   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise/files/halite_gem/poise/helpers/option_collector.rb:98:in
> `option_collector_attribute'   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise/files/halite_gem/poise/helpers/option_collector.rb:83:in` attribute'
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise/files/halite_gem/poise/helpers/template_content.rb:143:in
> `attribute'   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:67:in` class:Resource'
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:39:in
> `<module:PoiseArchive>'   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:28:in` module:Resources'
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:25:in
> `<module:PoiseArchive>'   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources/poise_archive.rb:24:in` <top (required)>'
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/resources.rb:17:in
> `<top (required)>'   /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/files/halite_gem/poise_archive/cheftie.rb:17:in` <top (required)>'
> /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise-archive/libraries/default.rb:19:in
> `<top (required)>'
>
> Relevant File Content:
> ---------------------- /Users/admin/bootstrap/chef/conf/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/poise/files/halite_gem/poise/helpers/option_collector.rb:
>
> 91:          # @param name [String, Symbol] Name of the attribute to
> define.  92:          # @param default [Hash] Default value for the
> options.  93:          # @param parser [Proc, Symbol] Optional parser
> method. If a symbol it is  94:          #   called as a method on
> self. Takes a non-hash value and returns a  95:          #   hash of
> its parsed representation.  96:          # @param forced_keys
> [Array, Set] Method names that will be forced  97:
>
> ## to be options rather than calls to the parent resource.  98>>         def option_collector_attribute(name, default: {}, parser: nil,
>
> forced_keys: Set.new)  99:            raise Poise::Error.new("Parser
> must be a Proc or Symbol: #{parser.inspect}") if parser &&
> !(parser.is_a?(Proc) || parser.is_a?(Symbol)) 100:            # Cast
> to a set at definition time. 101:            forced_keys =
> Set.new(forced_keys) unless forced_keys.is_a?(Set) 102:            #
> Never allow name to be called accidentally since it does really wonky
> things. 103:            forced_keys.add(:name) 104:            #
> Unlike LWRPBase.attribute, I don't care about Ruby 1.8. Worlds tiniest
> violin. 105:            define_method(name.to_sym) do |arg=nil,
> &block| 106:              iv_sym = :"@#{name}" 107:
>
> System Info:
> ------------ chef_version=17.0.242 platform=mac_os_x platform_version=10.15.4 ruby=ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision
> 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-darwin18] program_name=/usr/local/bin//chef-client
> executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client

Comment: **This error is caused by the latest version of chef (chef 17) which is release 28-April-2021. with this version poise-ruby  cookbook fail . using older version of chef (chef-16) works smooth.**

Answer (score 1):

The poise-archive cookbook has been deprecated and archived for a long time:

https://github.com/poise/poise-archive

On Chef Infra 17.0 those poise_archive resources should be converted to archive_file resources which do not require an external cookbook:

https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file

The poise cookbooks being broken is not a bug which will be fixed.

Comment: Any idea if the same is true for poise-python? I am seeing the same behavior from that cookbook as well.

Comment: Yes poise-python is also deprecated and archived.